# Upper triangular matrix and nilpotent

Tags: matrices

How to show that an upper triangular matrix is nilpotent if and only if all its diagonal elements are equal to zero by using induction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be a upper triangular matrix of order $n$ and let us denote $a_{ij}^{(k)}$ the $(i, j)$ element of $A^k$.

- If $a_{ii}^{(1)} \neq 0$ for some $1 \leqslant i \leqslant n$ then you can prove by induction that $a_{ii}^{(k)} \neq 0$ for every $k \geqslant 1$.
- If all diagonal elements of $A$ are equal to zero, then you can prove by induction that for every $k \geqslant 2$, all elements within the [$k - 1$-diagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superdiagonal#Matrices) of the matrix $A^k$ (*i.e.* elements $a_{ij}^{(k)}$ such that $j = i + k$) are equal to zero.